# php ftp make multiple directories

Tags: php, ftp, makefile, subdirectory

Here is my PHP code. It actually works fine:

```
            $newftpdir_parent   = date('Ymd');                              // YYYYMMDD
            $newftpdir_child    = $ext_folder;                              // username
            $newftpdir          = $newftpdir_parent.'/'.$newftpdir_child;   // YYYYMMDD/username
            $conn_id            = ftp_connect($uptoftp_server);
            ftp_login($conn_id, $uptoftp_username, $uptoftp_pass);

            $path_of_storage    = $uptoftp_path_abs.'/'.$uptoftp_path_rel; // /var/www/uploads
            if( !@ftp_chdir($conn_id, $path_of_storage.'/'.$newftpdir_parent) ){
                  ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $path_of_storage.'/'.$newftpdir_parent);
                  ftp_chmod($conn_id, 0777, $path_of_storage.'/'.$newftpdir_parent);
            }
            if( !@ftp_chdir($conn_id, $path_of_storage.'/'.$newftpdir) ){
                  ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $path_of_storage.'/'.$newftpdir);
                  ftp_chmod($conn_id, 0777, $path_of_storage.'/'.$newftpdir);
            }

            ftp_chdir($conn_id, $path_of_storage.'/'.$newftpdir);

            ftp_put($conn_id, $file_name, $filetoftp, FTP_ASCII);

            ftp_close($conn_id);
```

It uploads a file from local server to remote ftp servers. As you can se there are 2 ugly if conditions that check if directory exists, if not we create it and move in it. And again for subdir. Since I now want my directories (on the ftp servers) to look like YYYY/MM/DD/username instead of YYYYMMDD/username, I will need to create two more of these if blocks. It works great, but it does not look clean, I'm kind of maniac about it... I was wondering if there is better way to do it, since ftp_mkdir() cannot make multiple dirs (dir with subdirs in it)?

for exemple, considering only the /uploads/ dir exists, but not the /2013/ neither subdir /06/ and /11/ :

```
ftp_mkdir($conn_id, '/var/www/uploads/2013/06/11');
```

returns:

```
Warning: ftp_mkdir() [function.ftp-mkdir]: /var/www/uploads/2013/06/11: No such file or directory in /home/blabla/www/test.php on line 18
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<?php

// function
function ftp_mksubdirs($ftpcon,$ftpbasedir,$ftpath){
   @ftp_chdir($ftpcon, $ftpbasedir); // /var/www/uploads
   $parts = array_filter(explode('/',$ftpath)); // 2013/06/11/username
   foreach($parts as $part){
      if(!@ftp_chdir($ftpcon, $part)){
         ftp_mkdir($ftpcon, $part);
         //ftp_chmod($ftpcon, 0775, $part);
         ftp_chdir($ftpcon, $part);
      }
   }
}

// usage
$path_of_storage = '/var/www/uploads';
$newftpdir = '2013/06/11/username';

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftpserver);
ftp_login($conn_id, $login, $pass);
ftp_mksubdirs($conn_id,$path_of_storage,$newftpdir);
ftp_close($conn_id);

?>
```

Comment: great function, windows allows to create several folders at once /folder/subfolder/etc but Linux does not, this function is ideal for it

Comment: It saved my lot of time as I was going to make logic for this and before that just give a try to search it here and I found this amazing solution. Thank you for sharing it here.

Comment: there is a bug in this function! When you try to create this path: "/4/9/0/foo" it will result in  "/4/9/foo" due to PHP's array_filter() function.

Comment: 9 years later, still the perfect function. Merci!

Answer (score 2):

Found this, maybe it helps:

```
function ftp_mkdir_recusive($con_id,$path){
    $parts = explode("/",$path);
    $return = true;
    $fullpath = "";
    foreach($parts as $part){
            if(empty($part)){
                    $fullpath .= "/";
                    continue;
            }
            $fullpath .= $part."/";
            if(@ftp_chdir($con_id, $fullpath)){
               ftp_chdir($con_id, $fullpath);
            }else{
                    if(@ftp_mkdir($con_id, $part)){
                            ftp_chdir($con_id, $part);
                    }else{
                            $return = false;
                    }
            }
    }
    return $return;
}

$dir = "/2012/05/02/"

if(ftp_mkdir_recusive($con_id,$dir)){
     print("Successfully created $dir");
}else{
    print("There was a problem while creating $dir");
}
```

Comment: that's about the same, it still loops the same ftp_mkdir function, I was looking for a dedicated function actually. I also came across your solution (which does not work btw) on the php.net manual. Well if it's the only workaround... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### THIS IS SOLUTION

I Defined Completely Function You Can Use (I **TESTED** in **Wordpress**, **Doesn't Have Any Problem to use** ) :

```
function ftp_mksubdirs($con_id,$ftpbasedir,$path){
    // Set Base Dir
    if($ftpbasedir == null || ftp_chdir($con_id, $ftpbasedir)){
        //Check If Path is Exist, 
        $exist_ftp = ftp_nlist($con_id, $path);
        if ( (is_array($exist_ftp) && count($exist_ftp) > 0) || $exist_ftp == true ){
            // Path Is Exist, Move to $path
            ftp_chdir($con_id, $path);
            return true;
        }
        // Split Path
        $parts = explode("/",$path);
        
        // Check Part by Part Of Path
        foreach($parts as $part){
            // if Part is not Empty 
            if(!empty($part)){
                /////////////////////////////
                ///   ***  Filters  ***   \\\
                if(str_replace(" ","",$part) == ".."){
                    //Go To Parent Directory
                    ftp_cdup($con_id);
                    // Check Next $part
                    continue;
                
                }else if(str_replace(" ","",$part) == ".") {
                    //Ignore & pass
                    continue;
                }
                /// *** [END] Filters *** \\\
                /////////////////////////////
                // Check If Folder is Exist
                $exist_ftp2 = ftp_nlist($con_id, $part);
                if ( (is_array($exist_ftp2) && count($exist_ftp2) > 0) || $exist_ftp2 == true ){
                    // Folder Existed.
                    // Move Directory To this Folder
                    ftp_chdir($con_id, $part);
                }else{
                    //If Can Make Folder
                    if(ftp_mkdir($con_id, $part)){
                        // Move Directory To this Folder
                        ftp_chmod($con_id, 0777, $part);
                        ftp_chdir($con_id, $part);
                    }else {
                        // We can't Create Folder, Check Your User Permission.
                        //return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }// End Foreach
    }else{
        //Can't Set The Base
        // return ftp_mksubdirs($con_id,$ftpbasedir,$path);
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Example :

```
$path = "/hamid/reza/irani";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server, $ftp_server_port); 
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
// if you don't need to change base, set it to null; else : Your Path
// -> I Recommend set it ( the $base )
$base = '/'; // OR $base = null;
if(ftp_mksubdirs($con_id, $base, $path )){
     print("Successfully created $path");
}else{
    print("There was a problem while creating $path");
}
```

**if it's work for YOU!! Vote To Go Upper :)**