# The file is not being generated in the remote directory (ftp)

Tags: php, ftp

I am able to connect normally to filezilla (ftp). But the return from the `ftp_fput ()` method returns false. This means that you were unable to upload the file.

Here is my code:

```
$server = "host.host.ws";
$user = "username";
$pass = "password";
// call function
$conn = uploadFTP($server, $user, $pass, $local_file, $remote_file);
    
function uploadFTP($server, $username, $password, $local_file, $remote_file) {
    
    $connection = ftp_connect($server);
    if (@ftp_login($connection, $username, $password)){
        
        ftp_pasv($connection, true) or die("Unable switch to passive mode");
                            
        $fp = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');            
        fwrite($fp, 'content within the file');
        rewind($fp);

        // the file is not generated in the remote directory: /App/data/Json/File.json
        if (ftp_fput($connection, '/App/data/Json/File.json', $fp, FTP_ASCII)) 
            echo 'generated file!';

        fclose($fp);
        ftp_close($connection);
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

The file will only be generated when it displays the message: "generated file!", But it is not what is happening.

The code doesn't show any explicit errors, my question is, why doesn't this code generate the file in the directory? Could you share a solution to this problem?

Comment: Show us a log file from any commandline/GUI FTP client for a successful upload of the same file. + Show us how you check that *"it is not what is happening"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps FTP gives access to the root directory and you need to provide the full path `/var/www/App/data/Json/File.json`

```
ftp_fput($connection, '/var/www/App/data/Json/File.json', $fp, FTP_ASCII)
```

The error is not visible because suppression is on.
Remove symbolically here "@" and use `error_get_last()` To see error information

```
if (ftp_login($connection, $username, $password)) {
    echo 'Connected!';
    
    
    if (ftp_fput($connection, '/App/data/Json/File.json', $fp, FTP_ASCII)) {
        echo 'generated file!';
    } else {
        print_r(error_get_last());
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
```

You need to make sure the directory structure is created on the server `/App/data/Json/` If not, then create it

I think it will be useful
[php ftp make multiple directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051118/php-ftp-make-multiple-directories)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I removed the '@', it showed no error. I was able to connect normally to that part. The problem is the ftp_fput method, it is returning false.

Comment: You need to make sure the directory structure is created on the server

Comment: yes, the structure /App/data/Json is defined on the server

Comment: Added error output error_get_last(). Perhaps FTP gives access to the root directory and you need to specify /var/www/App/data/Json/File.json

Comment: The answer cannot solve the problem. Was it the path suggestion in the comment above that solved your problem (what seems likely)? Then let us know, so that the @SeniorFullstack can update the answer to be meaningful. Otherwise this question is moot.